# Using camera through Platform channel

Tags: flutter

I have a java code that using OCR library, is it possible to use java code (init camera, recognition, result) to use with platform channels?
I dont know how to use activity from java code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use OCR in flutter, just use OCR library in pub.dev like

> [flutter_mobile_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobile_vision)

But if you want to custom you need to create your platform channel in native code.

Comment: I have an OCR engine. I should implement it into flutter plugin.